# Set Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK using java.time.DayOfWeek

Tags: java

Currently I've got some code that sets the DAY_OF_WEEK on a calendar based on a java8 java.time.DayOfWeek Object. Since the integer values for these types are misaligned, i.e.

> Calendar.SUNDAY == 1
>
> where as
>
> DayOfWeek.SUNDAY == 7

I was wondering if there was a recommended way to convert from one to the other. Currently I'm doing this.

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek.getValue() == 7 ? 1 : dayOfWeek.getValue() + 1);
```

Comment: `(dayOfWeek.getValue() % 7) + 1`?

Comment: Did you check WeekFields for your Locale?

Comment: @mylenereiners could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to convert from Calendar days to DayOfWeek and back:

```
fun dayOfWeekToCalendarDay(day: DayOfWeek): Int {
    return (day.value % 7) + 1
}

fun calendarDayToDayOfWeek(calendarDay: Int): DayOfWeek {
    val temp = (calendarDay + 6) % 7
    return if (temp == 0) DayOfWeek.SUNDAY else DayOfWeek.of(temp)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, the most robust way is to implement something like this:

From `Int` to `DayOfWeek`:

```kotlin
fun calendarToDayOFWeek(dayOfWeek: Int) = when(dayOfWeek) {
    Calendar.MONDAY -> DayOfWeek.MONDAY
    Calendar.TUESDAY -> DayOfWeek.TUESDAY
    Calendar.WEDNESDAY -> DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY
    Calendar.THURSDAY -> DayOfWeek.THURSDAY
    Calendar.FRIDAY -> DayOfWeek.FRIDAY
    Calendar.SATURDAY -> DayOfWeek.SATURDAY
    Calendar.SUNDAY -> DayOfWeek.SUNDAY
    else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect day specified")
}
```

From `DayOfWeek` to `Int`:

```kotlin
fun dayOfWeekToCalendar(dayOfWeek: DayOfWeek) = when(dayOfWeek) {
    DayOfWeek.MONDAY -> Calendar.MONDAY
    DayOfWeek.TUESDAY -> Calendar.TUESDAY
    DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY -> Calendar.WEDNESDAY
    DayOfWeek.THURSDAY -> Calendar.THURSDAY
    DayOfWeek.FRIDAY -> Calendar.FRIDAY
    DayOfWeek.SATURDAY -> Calendar.SATURDAY
    DayOfWeek.SUNDAY -> Calendar.SUNDAY
}
```

This may look like a lot of code, but the method is much more readable than any arithmetical operations on the enumeration `values` list.

Answer (score 0):

First you should of course avoid the poorly designed and long outdated `Calendar` class with subclasses if you can. With the amounts of legacy code we have around  these days, this is not always possible.

I don’t think there’s an official recommendation for how to convert, and I am pretty sure that tastes differ. One of my own first priorities would be if I could avoid doing the math myself since it’s unavoidable that it gets a bit hard to read. The comment by user745733 inspired me: I can. The built-in `WeekFields.SUNDAY_START` object numbers the days of the week in the same way `Calendar` does, from Sunday = 1 through Saturday = 7. Let’s use that.

```
    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.TUESDAY;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek.get(WeekFields.SUNDAY_START.dayOfWeek()));
    System.out.println("" + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + " " + calendar.getTime());
```

Output when I ran just now:

> 3 Tue Jun 04 18:25:33 CEST 2019

I got 3 and Tuesday as expected. I have tested with Saturday, Sunday and Monday too.

### From `Calendar` to `DayOfWeek`

The other way, provided that what you have got is really a `GregorianCalendar`, it’s not so bad (some locales will give you a different subclass of `Calendar`, though).

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    DayOfWeek dow = ((GregorianCalendar) calendar).toZonedDateTime().getDayOfWeek();
    System.out.println("" + calendar.getTime() + " => " + dow);
```

> Sat Jun 08 18:32:38 CEST 2019 => SATURDAY

Answer (score -2):

**DayOfWeek** is an enum representing the 7 days of the week - Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday and Sunday, Which is followed by the ISO-8601 standard, from 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday).
For more info [click here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html)

But in Calender class it was given in different way i.e., from Sunday(1) to Saturday(7).[see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK).

The approach you are following is good i guess.

Answer (score -3):

Better solution would be Georgian calendar which will work in better way.

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

> dayOfWeek = 1 then Sunday .... dayOfWeek = 7 then Saturday

Comment: This doesn't attempt to answer OPs question how to convert from one to the other.